# NeDB ensureIndex isn't working as expected

Tags: node.js, json, nedb

I'm working on a twitter bot that is supposed to search the twitter api for key words in intervals and log the response in a database. I've so far logged results in a simple JSON but want to move to NeDB. I keep running into this error (shortened) while attempting to only have unique records stored:

Error: Cannot create an index without a fieldName
at Datastore.ensureIndex
{
missingFieldName: true
}

The code in question reads as follows:

```
async function logCleanTweets(array) {
  db.insert(array);
  db.ensureIndex({fieldname: 'id', unique: true}, function (err) {console.log(err);});
  db.persistence.compactDatafile();
  return uniqueArray.length
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: `fieldname` should be changed to `fieldName`. If you ment `_id ` its indexable and uniqe by default. Also `uniqueArray` is undefined

Comment: I would also recommend that you switch to [NeDB-promises](https://github.com/bajankristof/nedb-promises) as its currently maintained and uses async await instead of callbacks

Comment: Thank you! I saw this way too late but appreciate your input a lot!